# set TextView from in Fragment from activity

Tags: android, date, android-studio, android-fragments, textview

I try to modify a date in my `Fragment` through a dialog that is declared in my activity but I can not edit the `TextView` from my activity

this part is declared in my activity

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                myDateListener, year, month, day);
    } 
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0,
                                  int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // arg1 = year
                // arg2 = month
                // arg3 = day
                showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
            }
        };

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

     abbes = new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year);
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new Fragment7();
    Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Radio", String.valueOf(abbes));
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+abbes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

I checked with a `Toast` when I change the date through the dialog in my activity it changes, so I tried to send the string to my `Fragment` only it sends nothing and I have not understood why!

> And in my `Fragment`

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {
        abbes1 = this.getArguments().getString("Radio");
        name.setText(abbes1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data from your fragment to your container activity. You can simply use an interface to do this. You need to pass the data to an interface method. Implement that interface in your activity, override it's method, and you will have your data in the activity. This is the most modular approach, and it avoids memory leaks too. For reference you can have a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Otherwise, you can directly call the method of your container Activity from your fragment and pass the data value in it. Like this: `((YourContainerActivity)getActivity()).yourMethodInActivity(yourParams);`

For sendind data from activity to fragment:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
    // set Fragmentclass Arguments
    Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_layout,fragobj,"FragmentClass");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In your fragment, you can use getArguments() to get the bundle.

Comment: i want send data to my fragment from my activity !

Comment: to need to navigate to your fragment by replacing your activity container layout with the fragment.

Comment: When I open the fragment the textview is not changed, I must open the dialog box for it to be modified!